# Output some sections of a text file

Tags: sed, awk, perl

I have input like the following:

```
>gi|481443199|gb|MH447771.1|
49      0       0       0       1
50      0       0       1       0
>gi|987078004|gb|RTYJ01067061.1|
412     0       0       1       0
413     1       0       0       0
>gi|557075006|gb|ERTJ01078061.1|
41     0       0       1       0
41     1       0       0       0
>gi|787073002|gb|WERJ01045061.1|
612     0       0       1       0
613     1       0       0       0
>gi|887079001|gb|WERJ01045061.1|
715     0       0       1       0
716     1       0       0       0
```

I want to print some lines, but skip every other line that starts with `>` (along with all the lines after it, until the subsequent `>`). For the example input above, the output would be:

```
>gi|481443199|gb|MH447771.1|
49      0       0       0       1
50      0       0       1       0
>gi|557075006|gb|ERTJ01078061.1|
41     0       0       1       0
41     1       0       0       0
>gi|887079001|gb|WERJ01045061.1|
715     0       0       1       0
716     1       0       0       0
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To skip every other `> ...` block:

```
 awk '/^>/ { p = !p } p' input.txt
```

`p` is a print flag - `p` means print when `p` is true, as the default action is `print` when none is provided.  In `awk`, variables start out empty, which evaluates to false in Boolean contexts.  Every time a `> ...` line is reached, toggle the `p` flag.

To print every `n`th block delimited by `> ...` lines:

```
awk -v n=200 '/^>/ { if (skip == 0) skip = n - 1; else --skip; } skip == n - 1' input.txt
```

It's similar logic, except since `n` is not 2 we have to use a counter instead of a Boolean flag.  Here, `skip` counts how many more `> ...` lines to skip before we start printing again.  I'm using `skip == n - 1` as the print flag as a bit of a short cut.

Comment: sorry, as I am new to awk, Could you please explain me. In my question I asked to skip every 2nd ">", what I can do If want to skip every 200 occuring ">"

Comment: +1 for nice and simple in your first solution. The second command does not work though, it prints the 1st line and then each n+1th line after that. I.e. for n=4, it will print the 1st,6th,11th,16th etc instead of 1st,5th,9th,13th etc.

Comment: @terdon You are right, I had an off-by-1 bug.  I feel slightly embarrassed lol. :P

Comment: No worries, happens to the best of us :)

Answer (score 3):

For awk you can do:

```
awk 'BEGIN{pr=true}/^>/{pr=!pr}{if (pr) {print}}'
```

This sets a flag (pr) for when to print, that is toggled every appearance of your token.

Answer (score 3):

```
$ awk '/^>/{f=f?0:1;}f' file
```

Just switching a flag variable on and off on encoutering a line beginning with '^'. When it is on, print lines, else don't.

Answer (score 1):

For a more general solution, you can try this:

```
awk 'k%10==0{print} /^>/ {k++}' input.txt
```

This increments the variable `k` every time a line starts with `>` and prints the lines if k modulo 10 is 0. So, if you want to print every 2nd line, change `k%10==0` to `k%2==0`, for every 200th line change it to `k%200==0` etc.

WARNING: In this version, the first line will ALWAYS be printed.